# Ubuntu 20.04 slow boot issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-time

After experimenting with some suggested remedies to similar boot issues in the forum, my hp pavilion g4 notebook (i5, 4GB RAM) (Windows+Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop dual boot) took much longer time to boot.

The following is a result of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` command.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 25.876s
└─multi-user.target @2min 25.875s
  └─kerneloops.service @37.747s +55ms
    └─network-online.target @37.711s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @25.803s +11.905s
        └─NetworkManager.service @20.934s +4.866s
          └─dbus.service @20.928s
            └─basic.target @20.885s
              └─sockets.target @20.885s
                └─snapd.socket @20.884s +973us
                  └─sysinit.target @20.754s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @20.096s +657ms
                      └─apparmor.service @19.350s +743ms
                        └─local-fs.target @19.349s
                          └─run-user-125.mount @1min 9.857s
                            └─swap.target @18.940s
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a914a306\x2df035\x2d4689\x2>
                                └─dev-sda10.device @18.799s
```

Another reading after an update gives

```
graphical.target @4min 41.087s
└─multi-user.target @4min 41.087s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @2min 10.410s +192ms
    └─snapd.service @1min 38.321s +32.083s
      └─basic.target @1min 38.060s
        └─sockets.target @1min 38.060s
          └─snapd.socket @1min 38.058s +1ms
            └─sysinit.target @1min 37.932s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @1min 35.399s +2.533s
                └─apparmor.service @1min 34.569s +828ms
                  └─local-fs.target @1min 34.568s
                    └─run-user-125.mount @2min 29.511s
                      └─swap.target @1min 32.223s
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a914a306\x2df035\x2d4689\x2da00c\>
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a914a306\x2df035\x2d4689\x2da00
```

I suspect a possible graphic card error (hybrid intel+radeon) as I could see many error against [radeon] during startup.

Any suggestion/help in this regard is highly needed. Thanks!

**Edits**

After disabling snap as suggested by @kanehekili, the boot did better.

```
graphical.target @58.062s
└─multi-user.target @58.062s
  └─networkd-dispatcher.service @18.226s +13.683s
    └─basic.target @18.167s
      └─sockets.target @18.167s
        └─uuidd.socket @18.167s
          └─sysinit.target @17.777s
            └─systemd-timesyncd.service @17.257s +519ms
              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @16.868s +322ms
                └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.667s +12.200s
                  └─systemd-journald.service @3.251s +1.410s
                    └─systemd-journald.socket @3.230s
                      └─-.mount @3.209s
                        └─system.slice @3.209s
                          └─-.slice @3.209s
```

and $ dmesg gives a lot less red colors than when I did during my post in the comments!

**P.S.** I recently installed sagemath.

Comment: snap again. Without starting to rant I'd advise to disable snap, install some of the apps (like gnome caclulator) the "old" way via apt-get. Snap destroys the Linux ecosystem, my opinion...  Still -besides snap - your chain looks sick. What does dmesg say after boot? My Ubuntu starts within 20 seconds (no snap)

Comment: disabling snap does not help much and dmesg does not look good as I see lots of red colours. I was wondering if the boot file I had written in the root { / } during the dual boot installation could be a reason? This is my third installation and I have this boot lag issue every time.

Comment: Very [relevant article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process) ... the details differ, but I have managed to cut down the boot time of an RPi2 (also not the strongest hardware) from around one and a half minutes to under 15 seconds.  If that `systemd-journal-flush.service` service is slow, it could be slow storage. The networkd dispatcher taking so long could be a configuration issue (auto-connected VPN ...). Check out all the scripts and configuration in `/etc/networkd-dispatcher`. For services you don't use `disable` or `mask` them ...

Comment: If you see a lot of red colors then it looks like that your hardware is not fully supported. Especially AMD Radeon cards lack any decent support in Linux (because AMD is not providing any information about their stuff)

Comment: Uh, that might be the case! The other day, while booting up I could see a lot of error messages against [radeon] on the screen prior to the ubuntu logo. Guess, I should check if there is any solution to amd graphic card issues with linux?

Comment: Thanks. I rechecked the $ dmesg again and could see quite a lot of *reds and yellow flags* against Radeon.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 20.04 starting slowly.
In the `/etc/fstab` file there were invalid entries about the partition, especially SWAP. This was due to, for example, having changed the partition setting after installing a new system.

They need to be corrected so that there is something similar:

```
# / etc / fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID = as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab (5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# / was on / dev / sdb2 during installation
UUID = f712dfe1-dfa2-48b1-af05-027eedf6j3c / ext4 errors = remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on / dev / sda2 during installation
UUID = 10ff2eec-b9ed-42ff-9ec4-1f534ek692e2 none swap sw 0 0
```

---

Partition numbers can be found e.g. by running the disk application (`gnome-disk-utility`).

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to post your solutions. I had already switched over to linux mint as I thought the problems in my ubuntu was also affecting my windows 7 (dual boot) since I got BSODs frequently (I even opened my laptop and cleaned the graphic cards). I am now running Linux Mint 19.3 only on my laptop and everything seems fine though I am not sure if my AMD graphic card is working well or not. Thinking of upgrading to Linux Mint 20 now. In hindsight, I think my problem had to do with my graphic card as I used to have graphic card related problems once in a while when in windows.